# Doubly Warped Products in Petersen's book

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am having a question about Section 1.4.5, Doubly Warped Products in Riemannian Geometry, 3rd (Petersen).

In section 1.4.4, we consider rotationally symmetric metrics on $I\times S^{n-1}$, $$ dt^2 + \rho^2(t)ds_{n-1}^2 $$ where $ds_{n-1}^2$ is the standard metric on the sphere. We wish to study the case where $\rho(0) = 0$ and $\rho(t)>0$ for $t>0$ and see if the metric extends smoothly near $t=0$. For this problem, my understanding is that we give $\mathbb{R}^n$ a metric that only depends on the distance to the origin, so in polar coordinate, it has the above form. Then in Petersen's book, it says if $\dot{\rho}(0) = 1$ and the even derivatives vanish $$\rho^{(even)}(0) = 0$$ then this metric extends smoothly to the origin.

(If my understanding is wrong, please let me know!)

Next, Petersen wants to consider the double warped product: on $I \times S^p \times S^q$ with the metric $$ dt^2 + \rho^2(t)ds_{p}^2 + \phi^2(t)ds_{q}^2$$ Suppose the smoothness for both functions and $\phi > 0$ on $I$. Again, we wish to study that if $\rho(0) = 0$ and $\rho(t)>0$ for $t>0$, then under what condition the metric extends smoothly at $t = 0$. The answer is given by the following Proposition:

> (Proposition 1.4.7) With above assumptions, we get a smooth metric at $t=0$ if and only if  $$ \rho^{(even)}(0) = 0, \dot{\rho}(0) = 1$$ and $$ \phi(0) > 0, \phi^{odd}(0) = 0 $$

My question is, how should I interpret the metric $dt^2 + \rho^2(t)ds_{p}^2 + \phi^2(t)ds_{q}^2$ on Euclidean space? Also, why do we have derivative constraints on $\phi$ even if $\phi>0$ at all time (especially $\phi(0)>0$)?

Comment: (The word is "warped", not "wraped".)

Comment: @JasonDeVito Oh, thank you for pointing out the typo!

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit the problem here is a little bit subtle. In general, if we consider a metric $dt^2+\rho^2(t)ds_p^2$ on $I\times S^p$, the condition $\rho(t)>0$, $\forall t$ is necessary to keep positive while smoothness is automatically satisfied. But if we interpret $I\times S^p= \mathbb{R}^{p+1}$, the positiveness and smoothness refers to positiveness and smoothness under coordinate $x_1,...,x_{p+1}$. When comes to the case of doubly warped product,  the metric should considered on $\mathbb{R}^{p+1}\times S^q$(If you look at the Proposition1.4.7 in Peterson's book, this interpretation is reasonable). If we adopt the convention in Peterson's book, we can compute
$$dt^2+\rho^2(t)ds_p^2+\phi^2(t)ds_q^2=\left(\frac{1}{t^2}-\frac{\rho^2(t)}{t^4}\right)\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p+1}x_idx_i\right)^2+\frac{\rho^2(t)}{t^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p+1}dx_i^2+\phi^2(t)ds_q^2.$$It should be reminded that the smoothness is not for $t$ but for the indeterminants $x_1,...,x_{p+1}$. Here $$t=|x|=\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{p+1}x_i^2}$$ is not smooth at $(0,...,0)$, so in order to keep smooth we have to exert additional condition $\phi^{\text{odd}}(0)=0$. To ensure positiveness, $\phi(0)>0$ is necessary.

Comment: How do you interpret $I\times S^p$ as $\Bbb R^{p+1}$?

Comment: $I\times S^p\cong \mathbb{R}^{p+1}\backslash\{0\}$, so using this identification (if you wanna be more rigorous, use a diffeomorphism to pull back) the metric is automatically smooth on $\mathbb{R}^{p+1}\backslash\{0\}$. Now smoothness of $g$ means extending $g$ smoothly to the whole $\mathbb{R}^{p+1}$. @TedShifrin